# Uwsim how to add Mass to terrain cirs_trident

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using UWSIM package.
I loaded the CIRS scene. Everything is working fine. My problem is that the AUV passes through the wall of the terrain. I tried adding some mass to my terrain, but it sank when I gave it mass. Is there a particular way to do it? I jut want my AUV to collide with the walls of the terrain and not pass through it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205491/uwsim-how-to-add-mass-to-terrain-cirs_trident/) by [User_810](https://answers.ros.org/users/21697/user_810/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In order to have collision responses you need to launch the dynamic module and use a force sensor as input for external forces on it. You can directly launch it using the launchfile in underwater_vehicle_dynamics using "roslaunch underwater_vehicle_dynamics UWSim_g500_dynamics.launch", The results should be the same as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74R75S8cqgQ).

Hope it helps!

Edited: As you experimented in your comment I forgot to say you will need to send messages to the thrusters input ("/g500/thrusters_input" by default) it's a Float64Multiarray setting the effort to vehicle's thrusters from -1 to 1. In the case of girona 500 model it uses 5 thrusters first two forward/backward, the second pair up/down and the last one for lateral movements, this can be configured through a yaml on the underwater_vehicle_dynamics package although is not straight forward. SetVehiclePose and setVehiclePosition won't work in this mode of work as dynamics module is controlling positions and velocities.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [User_810](https://answers.ros.org/users/21697/user_810/) on 2015-03-24**:
Hello, Yes it helped me.
But I still have some questions. I am trying to use the functions setVehicleVelocity and setVehiclePose now. But the movement of the AUV doesn't seem correct now. Is it supposed to be different with this dynamic module?

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2015-03-24**:
True, I edited the previous answer ;)